# Refining Clash Detection: Excluding Nested Components

Tags: python, detection

I have developed a tool in Revit using Python for clash detection. However, this tool also detects components that are supposed to nest geometrically with other components, such as beams with columns. I used this tool in a project where there were no unacceptable intersections between components. Despite this, the tool interpreted the connection between the beam and column as a clash, for example. Is there any way to prevent the tool from detecting clashes between these nesting components?

the coding of this tool :

```
``import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import \*
from Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection import \*

# Initialize the Revit application and document objects

app = __revit__.Application
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document

# Get the current selection

selection = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Selection

# Get the selected elements and filter by category

allowed_cat = \[BuiltInCategory.OST_StructuralFraming, BuiltInCategory.OST_StructuralColumns, BuiltInCategory.OST_Floors\]
selected_element_ids = selection.GetElementIds()
elements = \[doc.GetElement(e_id) for e_id in selected_element_ids if doc.GetElement(e_id).Category.BuiltInCategory in allowed_cat\]

# Check if any suitable elements were selected

if not elements:
forms.alert('No suitable elements were selected. Please select at least one structural framing, column, or floor element and try again.', title=__title__, exitscript=True)

# Define a function to check if two bounding boxes intersect

def intersect_bbox(bbox1, bbox2):
return (bbox1.Min.X \<= bbox2.Max.X and bbox1.Max.X \>= bbox2.Min.X and
bbox1.Min.Y \<= bbox2.Max.Y and bbox1.Max.Y \>= bbox2.Min.Y and
bbox1.Min.Z \<= bbox2.Max.Z and bbox1.Max.Z \>= bbox2.Min.Z)

# Define a list to store the clash results

clash_results = \[\]

# Perform a bounding box intersection test between all selected elements

for i in range(len(elements)):
for j in range(i+1, len(elements)):
elem1 = elements\[i\]
elem2 = elements\[j\]
bbox1 = elem1.get_BoundingBox(None)
bbox2 = elem2.get_BoundingBox(None)
if intersect_bbox(bbox1, bbox2):
clash_results.append((elem1, elem2))

# Print the clash results to the console

if clash_results:
print("Clash Results:")
for result in clash_results:
print("Elements {0} and {1} intersect.".format(result\[0\].Id, result\[1\].Id))
else:
print("No Clashes Detected.")`
```

Comment: Please remove the extraneous backslashes and backticks from your code block. It is currently not runnable.